# Teleporting mobs in a specific radius up 50 blocks relative to themself

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I am making a school project in Minecraft where I teleport a chunk of the the land around me 50 blocks in to the air. I also want to teleport all mobs in the same area up to the chunk that I moved. I have already found out the height I need to teleport myself up, but is there some way to take the mobs around me relative to themselfes up 50 blocks?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven’t really tried much since i am not so well known with minecraft coding blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To teleport an entity or player relative to itself, you first need to change the **execution context** to be at that entities position. This is best achieved using the execute command as follows:

*(not entirely sure whether education edition has the new execute command yet, so here are both versions)*
*old:*

```
execute <the entities> ~ ~ ~ tp ~ ~50 ~
```

*new:*

```
execute as <the entities> at @s run tp ~ ~50 ~
```

Comment: If i use this code won’t i have to write the same code for every different type of mob I want to teleport?

Comment: that solely depends on your entity selector. if you use `@e` without a `type` or `family` selector (and only a region selector) then it will teleport every entity in the area.

Comment: Oh yeah. I knew that, but i forgot it

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way